# HTML/CSS: floating divs height and bottom vertical align

Tags: css, html, css-float

I can't make HTML layout described as in jsFiddle link below, using `<div>` and CSS `float`. With `table` tag I can solve this problem, but I need DIV+CSS solution. It's possible? Anyone can help?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="column">

Some content!<br/>
Some content!<br/>
Some content!<br/>
Some content!<br/>
Some content!<br/>

</div>

 <div>

Something on top

</div>

    <div id="bottom-content" style="background-color: #FA0">

Something with vertical align = bottom AND height == height of left column

</div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    background-color: grey;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKnw9/8/)**

Solution:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="column">

Some content!<br/>
Some content!<br/>
Some content!<br/>
Some content!<br/>
Some content!<br/>

</div>

 <div style="float:left; height:82px">

Something on top

</div> 

    <div id="bottom-content" style="background-color: #FA0; float:left;">

Something with vertical align = bottom AND height == height of left column

</div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    background-color: grey;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
```

Comment: What layout are you after? If it's a table of data then just use tables.

Comment: Exactly, what kind of layout is it? Is it a website, a table full of data? This kind of question has been answered _so many times_ try searching for "floated layout" or "two/three column layout" on Google or StackOverflow..

Comment: Can you post a screnshot of desired output (use tables if necessary to create the screenshot).

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2325784/example_layout.png it's example. I need to move rating stars at the bottom of div.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

as i m getting your question.You need to give float on your div

jsfiddle.net/tKnw9/12

check the fiddle

Comment: thanks, but i need thats orange block will be below white block.

Comment: its below only ... u want that block below the gray  block

Comment: hmm...i want this: gray block to the left side of page, white block to the right side of gray block (with vertical align - top), orange block - to the right side of gray block and below white block (with vertical align - bottom).

Comment: i will be glad if you will add the snapshot what u exactly want :-)

Comment: I want this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2325784/example_layout.png , but I want that stars will be at bottom line of image on left side on screenshot :-) Sorry for my english..

Comment: Sorry, but I see no difference. I need this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2325784/example_jsfiddle.png

Comment: Your answer should be posted here, and not as a link to a third party site.

Comment: The link in your answer is outdated. You didn't provide the code, nor explained how you've solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The layout(i.e. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2325784/example_layout.png) can be achieved with the following code I guess:

```
.container {
    width:900px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.picture{
    float:left;
    width:220px;
}
.column {
    width:320px;
    float: left;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

& the HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="picture">Picture</div>
    <div class="column">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Genere</td>
                <td>Arcade</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Micheal A. Denio</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Publisher</td>
                <td>Micheal A. Denio</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Released</td>
                <td>1988</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Platform</td>
                <td>DOS</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rating 1</td>
                <td>Rating Picture will goes here</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rating 2</td>
                <td>Rating2 Pic will goes here</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you do not want to use table you can achieve this with `ul` & `li` combination.

Cheers!